# Can I take a sex-toy on plane through UAE?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, legal, uae, sex

I will be traveling from Australia to Austria, transferring in Abu Dhabi. Is it alright for me to bring a vibrator in the check-in luggage, or are there laws against that?

It is approximately 17cm long. Are there any precautions to take?

Comment: If you're merely transiting, it's unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: Since the sale of such toys to adults in Singapore is legal, I am not sure if this would be a pertinent question at all (if we split it separately into Signapore and UAE) unless the toy is specifically a sharp tool that can hurt people (in a strict safety sense)

Comment: Protip: if it gets detected, don't claim it's a bomb. (Someone allegedly once did that)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Upon landing at Abu Dhabi; you and your luggage will be subject to an x-ray scan. At this point, any suspicious items will be confiscated.

Although you are not importing items into the UAE (as you never enter the country, but are in transit) nevertheless any goods deemed inappropriate will be seized.

You do run the risk of having the item confiscated *but nothing more*.

Comment: Does this hold for checked bags, too, or just cabin luggage?

Comment: It includes checked luggage as well.

Comment: Do you have a reference that this does happen to *transit* passengers' checked bags? I don't doubt this is true for passengers whose *destination* is Abu Dhabi, but it sounds strange for transit passengers who haven't legally-speaking crossed the UAE border. Abu Dhabi is actively promoting itself as a transit terminal, I'd be surprised if they'd do something like this that might complicate business

Comment: Yes, as it was featured in an episode of Ultimate Airport Dubai as transit passengers were found to be carrying live animals in their check-in luggage. As customs is a function of the _federal government_, the same applies across the UAE.

Comment: @user568458 Even when you are in transit and haven't passed immigration or customs, you are still on UAE soil and must expect to be subject to most UAE laws. A similar situation would be if you fly between two locations, in which cannabis is legalized, but transit through a third location where cannabis is illegal. Even if you for the purpose of immigration or customs don't enter the transit country, you would still be breaking the local laws by being in posession of an illegal substance.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I actually thought it was the opposite because - as I understand it - there's no problem in transiting through countries where alcohol is illegal with alcohol in your checked baggage, so long as it's never on your person and doesn't pass immigration or customs (could be wrong)

Comment: @user568458 Another example of where this applies is the US. Many people buy medicines in Canada and then are surprised when they are confiscated in the US because they are not permitted in the country - even though they are in transit to another destination.

Comment: @user568458 The IATA information page on customs rules for Saudi Arabia lists especially alcohol and pork products as prohibited for transit passengers. I am not sure why you expect transit passengers to be exempt from general laws in the country they are transiting? http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/SA-Saudi-Arabia-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm

Comment: @TorEinarJaenbjo In the specific case of the UAE they are not interested in tarnishing their reputation as a safe place for westerners to transit. Of course they could insist on applying their regulations to transit passengers, but as a matter of policy, it is sort of a "don't ask, don't tell" on sex/pornography and similar materials. Drugs and live animals are a different story.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Actually I think Dubai and Abu Dhabi customs are separate from "federal" customs, but then the UAE is not really a federation in the normal sense. The Emirates apply some regulations to transit passengers, but they are seriously concerned about reputation management. Upsetting people over sex toys left quietly in a bag doesn't serve their geopolitical strategy.

Comment: Most likely the person will have to explain what it is if its in their carry-on and it looks suspect on the scanner and the checked bag will pass.

Answer (score 9):

it gets confiscated and you get a fine of $250 USD and get asked to sign plenty of documents that you did that and that you wont do it again, all documents will be in arabic and not translated and they dont care about the fact that you cant read !!! it was the worst experience ever i hated the way i was treated and will never again stop or transit through abu dhabi

Comment: Thanka for sharing your experience.  Was your item in carry-on luggage, or checked luggage?

Answer (score -1):

I brought sex toys to Dubai from the USA on a few occasions, never had an issue. I think the custom will let go if it's few toys but not more as it will seem like you are a seller of sex toys.

Comment: Given the reports in some of the other answers, I'm not sure "I think..." is really a good basis for answering. Maybe you were just lucky.