# Planning to bring sex toys to Europe via Emirates

Tags: dubai, stopovers, sex

I'm planning to go to Europe via Emirates that will have a 3 hours stop over in Dubai.... And I'm planning to bring my sex toys with me....

I'm kinda worried since I just learned that sex toys are not allowed in Dubai....

I wonder if luggages are scanned again at the airport in Dubai before being transferred to the next flight.... (I know that if they scan the luggage, they will confiscate it and it is embarasing if seen in public)

Hoping for a fast response.....

Answer (score 0):

When arrive in Dubai on your first flight, you will go through airport security before you reach the main area of the terminal. Your carry-on bags will be X-ray'd and you will go through a metal detector. Your checked luggage will be transferred "behind the scenes" without you present (assuming you have purchased a single ticket for the trip), but it may be screened or searched somewhere in the depths of the airport.

We have [another question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59687/can-i-take-a-sex-toy-on-plane-through-uae/59692#59692) on this issue where Burhan Khalid reports:

> Although you are not importing items into the UAE (as you never enter
>   the country, but are in transit) nevertheless any goods deemed
>   inappropriate will be seized.
>
> You do run the risk of having the item confiscated but nothing more.

If you do decide to bring them anyway, there is presumably a much lower risk of public embarrassment if they are in your checked luggage.