# What kind of items related to sex can be carried to UAE?

Tags: luggage, security, dubai, uae, sex

So, apparently [I cannot bring a vibrator/dildo to the UAE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79729/planning-to-bring-sex-toys-to-europe-via-emirates/79730#79730), but is it acceptable to bring items like condoms, lubricant, handcuffs, whips (well, the small ones), and so on?
I'm especially interested in Dubai, and especially interested in the event of a **stay** for a holiday in the UAE, not just transit.

Answer (score 4):

Items that are available for sale in the UAE can be brought in without issue, so:

1. Condoms - yes.
2. Lubricant - yes.
3. Handcuffs - yes.
4. Whips - yes (as whips can be used for non-sex related stuff as well).

You can also leave most of that stuff at home since its readily available in most pharmacies, general and novelty stores.

There are, of course, no sex shops in Dubai.

Anything that can be used as a weapon is not allowed on carry-on luggage, as is the case anywhere else.