# Sex toys via Dubai

Tags: transit, airports, dubai

I am travelling to South Africa from the U.K. via Dubai and I have sex toys packed in my big check in bag. Will this be an issue? Will I get in trouble?

Comment: Related question [What kind of items related to sex can be carried to UAE?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102359/what-kind-of-items-related-to-sex-can-be-carried-to-uae)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of items related to sex can be carried to UAE?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102359/what-kind-of-items-related-to-sex-can-be-carried-to-uae)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I take a sex-toy on plane through UAE?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59687/can-i-take-a-sex-toy-on-plane-through-uae)

Comment: FTR, the previous iterations of this question do *not* answer the OP's specific question of bringing a toy through Dubai **in checked luggage**, as opposed to carry-on or bringing it into the country.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your toys are in **checked luggage**, they go straight through to your destination and you'll be fine.  (Bags *are* scanned for explosives etc, but this is largely automated and they don't care about the contents otherwise.)

However, if you have carry-on luggage or have a stopover in UAE, including any connection that requires you to recheck your bags (typically separate tickets), you run the risk of having your toys confiscated and possibly getting fined as well.

Do remember to remove batteries or fully discharge your toys before packing them though, airports don't like suitcases that make weird buzzing noises!

Comment: When a suitcase vibrates, then the throwers gotta call the police.  Nine times out of ten it’s an electric razor, but every once in a while, it’s a dildo.