# Where to put vibrator when transit flight goes through UAE and dubai

Tags: dubai, uae, sex

my girlfriend and I are flying from Ireland to Australia but have 2 stop overs in Dubai and Abu Dhabi, (about 3hrs for stop over in Dubai and 4 in Abu Dhabi, one self check-in and the other is just a connecting with no self-check in )

We have a vibrator, small and compact, are we able to put this in checked luggage or under stow luggage…?
Not really wanting a fine or to be out in prison because of it. Would it be best to throw out?

Comment: There are some answers [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59687/can-i-take-a-sex-toy-on-plane-through-uae), but I would appreciate an up-to-date answer that distinguishes between checked luggage and carry-on luggage.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that answer  but lower in the thread someone claims they were fined $250USD. Checked luggage meaning carry-on and understow meaning where they put under the plane? Not sure if this makes sense

Comment: Do you need it while travelling? Otherwise why don't you just get a new one in OZ if you are afraid of being arrested for a vibrator?

Comment: @Ruan checked luggage is the luggage you check in, i.e. not your carry-on luggage, but what you give to the airline to be put into the cargo hold. I've never heard of "understow".

Comment: yeah, either buy one on arrival if you can't live without one, or airmail it to your hotel in your name. Or just do without like most travelers.

Comment: you can take it with you on the flight to Dubai, "forget" it in the airplane on arrival, and abstain thereof until you get to Australia (about 12h)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I take a sex-toy on plane through UAE?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59687/can-i-take-a-sex-toy-on-plane-through-uae)

Comment: @jwenting _"Or just do without like most travelers."_ - Who says most travelers do without?

Comment: @marcelm What percentage of travelers do you think have sex toys in their luggage?

Comment: @AricTenEyck More than 50%, obviously ;) - But more seriously: plenty of people do, and it's normal to do so. The _"Or just do without like most travelers."_ I was reacting to comes across as a passive-aggressive way of judging OP and maintaining an unneccesary taboo on sex toys.

Comment: @marcelm Can you provide statistics to justify 'More than 50%', whether 'obviously' or not? I happen to believe AricTenEyck is wholly justified in asking and I strongly suspect your >50% is plucked out of thin air.

In more than 50 years of listening I've never heard it suggested anything like 50% of people use sex toys at all…

Are you suggesting even many, let or most of all who use sex toys are willing to risk flying them through strictly conservative jurisdictions, particularly when final destinations like Australia sell sex toys more cheaply on more high streets than in Ireland?

Comment: @marcelm Uh, what? This whole thing started not with you, but with Ruan posing a real Question, however naive. Your contributions seem to have been wholly asinine, at best, starting with your ridiculous 'More than 50%, obviously…'. How do you think this topic would suffer if all your Comments were deleted?

Comment: @Ruan Read it as “Just do without like most travellers *transiting a country where sex toys are illegal*” and jwenting’s comment becomes sound advice that is neither passive-aggressive or maintaining an unnecessary taboo on sex toys, IMHO

Answer (score 45):

Neither: **you should leave your vibrator at home**.  You can easily buy a new one in Australia.

If you have a "self-transfer" in DXB or AUH, you will need to take all your luggage, both checked in and carry on, through Customs, and this often involves getting it X-rayed.  Sex toys are illegal in the United Arab Emirates, so if it's spotted the consequences will be unpleasant, although most likely to be just a fine, not jail time.

Alternatively, instead of a naughty, illegal sex toy, you could bring along a perfectly legitimate handheld deep tissue massager like [this one sold in the UAE](https://www.amazon.ae/Go-Go-Handheld-Back-Massager-Interchangeable/dp/B07ZTLRHGX/ref=mp_s_a_1_19?keywords=back%20massager&qid=1697104569&sr=8-19).

Comment: Another option: mail it to your final destination.

Comment: Figure out the potential cost of the fine, and then spend up to that much on new ones at the destination.  Freight them home if desired, or dispose at the end of holiday.

Answer (score 6):

There are two aspects to this question: The black and white legal answer, and then the reality of the situation on the ground.
The legal answer is that sex toys are illegal, and if found, you will be subject to confiscation and/or a fine and/or jail time. As others have mentioned, just buy one at your destination and dispose of it before returning home.

The reality is that sex toys are readily available and people travel in and out (and through) the UAE with them regularly. Anecdotally, the worst case scenario is that you bag will be opened and the offending item will be removed, often without you even knowing (i.e. no TSA style "your bag has been checked" notice). But obviously your experience will vary - we where happy to take the risk!

Comment: In practice, I don't disagree, but the actual "worst case scenario" is jail time, not silent confiscation.  Why take the risk?

Comment: "The reality is that sex toys are readily available and people travel in and out (and through) the UAE with them regularly": citation needed. I doubt you have real data to back that up; at most you have personal experience, which is inevitably very limited. How many times did you do it? And do you know for sure of other people who did it and got away with it?

Comment: @lambshaanxy are there any news reports (or other publicly available information) concerning the imprisonment of travelers for the possession of sex toys or the disposition more generally of sex-toy-possession cases against travelers in transit at the airport?

Comment: @phoog The linked answer has somebody claiming they were fined. Also, the OP is doing a self-transfer, meaning they're not just transiting but entering the country.