will there be any problem if i bring sex toys in my cabin bag and have a transit at Dubai?
I am travelling from Canada to India , i have couple of small sex toys like lush 3, domi with me. and I have a layover at Dubai. will there be any problem?

And there are some others related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/102359/142000 |  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/59687/142000 | https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184079/142000
